# Как залить на github?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

Есть ветки master и test-develop.
Работал с проектом локально, внес изменения.

Раньше заливал на test-develop, а потом копировал на master, но уже забыл как это делал, а шпаргалку свою найти не могу.

Распишете пожалуйста по строчкам, что за чем идет и для чего.

Comment: например, можно [тут почитать](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: У вас в заголовке и в тексте разные вопросы )

Comment: Возможно. Пытаюсь разобраться, учусь...

Comment: Чтобы дополнить вопрос, не публикуйте ответы, а редактируйте: [edit]

Answer (score 3):

Вижу два разных вопроса:

#### Как из одной ветки копировать в другую:

```
# переключаемся на ту, куда копировать
git checkout master
# объединяем с той, из которой копируем
git merge test-develop
# если будут конфликты, правим их руками, а потом
git add .
git merge --continue
```

#### Как залить на github

```
# убеждаемся, что удалённый репозиторий вообще настроен
git remote -v

# переходим в нужную ветку и убеждаемся, что она не расходится с удаленным репозиторием
git checkout test-develop
git pull #тут могут быть конфликты
# пушим текущую ветку в новую удалённую и одновременно назначаем соответствие 
git push -u origin test-develop:

# в следующий раз можем пушить без указания подробностей
git checkout test-develop
git pull
git push

# можем запушить все локальные ветки сразу
git push --all
```

Answer (score 2):

если с удалённым репозиторием работаете не только вы, сначала надо получить все обновления из удалённого репозитория (и разрешить все, возможно возникшие в результате, конфликты):

```
$ git pull --all
```

---

после этого:

```
$ git push --all
```

этого достаточно для отправки **всех** локальных веток в удалённый репозиторий.

а так как ветки — это лишь указатели на коммиты, будут отправлены и все коммиты, недостающие в удалённом репозитории (но присуствующие в локальном).